# ANYLOGIC How can I change dinamically an agent position?

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm working on a model which simulates eartquake events and I need to execute a certain quantity of events, according a Poisson distribution. I would execute with a single run all events
that will follow one another in the same run. The events are represented by an epicenter (an agent called "epicenter") which appear on my GIS map that I've dropped in my model. So, is it possible to change epicenter position during the same run to execute all events in one run only? Thank you so much.

PS. I've added a picture just to give you a better idea of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can always change any agent's position using the `setXY(x, y)` method.

If this doesn't answer your actual question (it is really quite unclear), please refine the question following this advice: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Other answer? it is too general an answer, I could not solve the problem.

Comment: well, refine your question then, make our lives easy ;)

Comment: It’s so easy the question. Not your answer to understand. Avoid to make advertising to your site only. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Alfonso, your question was literally "How can I change dinamically an agent position?" . To which the answer is `setXY(double x, double y)`.  If your actual question was "So, is it possible to change epicenter position during the same run to execute all events in one run only?" then the answer is: yes. If you then want to know "well how?", the answer is (you guessed it) --> `setXY(double x, doubly y)`

Comment: Please understand how StackOverflow works, we are not here to spoon-feed you detailed answers, better use the LinkedIn forum for that. And if you want a resource that is not my website (sorry for trying to be helpful), see here on how to ask good SOF questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your website it’s not helpful. I’ve visited differents time, without serious helps. You advertising just your activity and your consulting acitivites for other companies.

Comment: If you don’t want my spoon feed answers, please don’t answer it anyway.  It’s no sense your approach to suggest topic presents already on the anylogic help.

Comment: I am sorry you feel that way. Do continue to ask questions, though. Will try to answer and help when I can :) Also, feel free to book a (free) consulting slot with me, happy to spend some 1-1 time and help you directly, it would be my pleasure: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/appointments . All the best :)